# Stringbuilder add new line inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, append

I'm trying to add a `new line` after looping through the group names inside of a `foreach` loop. However, it never adds the new line. Everything is printed in single line.

```
string [] groups = client.GetGroups(username.TrimEnd());

StringBuilder groupNames = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string groupName in groups)
{
   groupNames.Append(string.Format(groupName,Environment.NewLine));
}

Label1.Text = groupNames.ToString();
```

After reading few questions posted here in SO, I have tried many different solutions such as:

```
{
   groupNames.Append(groupName);
   groupNames.AppendLine();
}
Label1.Text = groupNames.ToString();
```

Also tried:

```
{ 
   groupNames.Append(groupName);
   groupNames.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
}
Label1.Text = groupNames.ToString();
```

However, if in any of the solution I add:

```
groupNames.Append("|");
//or
groupNames.Append(",");
```

it will work. The only thing is not working is the `newline`.

One thing to note is I'm grabbing the users `groupNames` from `Active Directory` and when the `groupNames` returned it contains `\` in the name. I also tried removing the `\` before adding new line, didn't work either.

```
groupNames.Append(groupName);
groupNames.Replace(@"\", " ");
groupNames.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In html new line is not `\r\n` but it's `<br>`, so you need to add `<br>` after each element, a simple `string.Join` should work fine:

```
var result = string.Join("<br>", groups);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I didn't think of that. `groupNames.Append("<br>");` did the magic.